# Error with Show when opening the notebook

Tags: plotting

Writing:

```
plots = {ParametricPlot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
         ParametricPlot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue]};

DynamicModule[{select = {1, 2}}, 
              Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[select], {1 -> "p1", 2 -> "p2"}], 
              Dynamic@Show[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}],          
              plots[[select]]]}]]
```

I get:

[image]

Unfortunately, if I save the notebook and close it, in the next reopening of the page I get the following error:

[image]

How can I avoid this error and get the following plot?

[image]

Also, I would like to get this default plot, but this is a secondary problem. Thank you!

Comment: Either put plots in `Initialization` or use `SaveDefinitions` for `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Let me know if you disagree with closing.